# how to join same table in mysql with custom result

Tags: mysql, select, join

I want to join self table to generate with query select.

**table A:**

```
ID || CID || STAT || VAL
...........................
A1 || (-) || 1 || 0
A2 || (-) || 1 || 0
A3 || (-) || 1 || 0
B1 || A1 || 2 || 20
B1 || A2 || 2 || 30
B2 || A1 || 2 || 40
B2 || A1 || 2 || 50
B3 || A1 || 2 || 60
```

i want to join table A with table A to generate a conditional result.
can anyone help me to make a result like this?

```
ID || CID || VAL
...........................
A1 || B1 || 20
A1 || B2 || 40
A1 || B2 || 50
A1 || B3 || 60
A2 || B1 || 30
A3 ||    ||
```

thanks for your attention.

Comment: Whats the logic behind this results?

Comment: no logic, just show select query like above. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *self-join* Table A to itself:

```
SELECT t1.ID, COALESCE(t2.ID, '') AS CID, COALESCE(t2.VAL, '')
FROM tableA t1 LEFT JOIN tableA t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.CID
WHERE t1.CID IS NULL
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: thx for your answer. sorry make you confuse for my question is fluctuate.. column "VALUE" not important, just show how the result works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.CID,a.ID,a.VAL FROM database.test a LEFT JOIN imt_database.test b ON a.CID = a.ID WHERE a.CID is not null
```

result :

```
A1  B1  20
A2  B1  30
A1  B2  40
A1  B2  50
A1  B3  60
```